# How do I change this if statement to test whether a character is present from the entry?

Tags: python, string, int, character

```
if '_' in self.entry.get():
                self.entry.insert(tk.END, " not accepted!")
```

How would I change the '_' to make it test whether a character is present?

I tried:

```
if chr in self.entry.get():
                self.entry.insert(tk.End, " not accepted!")
```

But the error said:
    'in ' requires string as left operand, not type

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You'll get much better responses if you give a sample input, expected output, and observed output.

Answer (score 0):

I think `chr` is a python builtin function so you can't use it like that in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from string import ascii_letters

if set(ascii_letters).intersection(set(self.entry.get())):
    self.entry.insert(tk.END, " not accepted!")
```

`ascii_letter` is a string with all the characters in the alphabet, by converting it to a set you can use set operation with it, like `intersection` which check if any of the elements in A are in B or vice-versa.

If you need the alphanumeric instead just add `digits` to the ascii_letters.

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

if set(ascii_letters+digits).intersection(set(self.entry.get())):
```

The `string` module also have the `punctuation` and `printable` which might suit your needs.